# como impedir que alguien ingrese a mi dashboard sin antes haber registrado en el formulario

Tags: php, javascript, base-de-datos, mysqli

```
/*mis archivos,| index.php | registros.php | conexion.php      //NOTA index.php es el login
```

redirección sino se ha registrado el login me envia al formulario de `registros.php` cuando introduzco los datos registros.php me envia a conexión.php en `conexion.php` me dice que me he registrado correctamente y es donde hace la conexión del formulario a la base de datos,

Mi problema es que si por ejemplo yo entro y escribo directamente en el navegador `conexion.php` el me lleva a esa pagina y me dice que me he registrado correctamente, como puedo impedir que eso pase?, me gustaría que ni digitando en el navegador `conexion.php` entre a esa pagina sino que la unica forma de ver esa pagina sea que me halla registrado en

```
registros.php
```

yo lo que estaba intentando hacer en mi codigo es que un javascript de que en esa pagina halla un `window.location.assign("index.php");` que siempre me redirigira a el login pero si en `registros.php` hacen bien el registro entonces en `registros.php`

hay un script que envia un `alert("se ha registrado correctamente pulse aceptar para continuar");` y después si continua en ir a `conexion.php`

agregaré este comentario más de como funciona la pagina hasta el momento,

Si alguien ingresa a dejar sus datos, el formulario envia los datos a mi base de datos correctamente y el script de alert dice el mensaje y que pulse aceptar, al pulsar aceptar me envia a la pagina principal del login

pero si alguien entra por el navegador sin digitar datos la pagina arroja un error y después se redirecciona ella misma a la pagina principal del login me gustaría que no mostrara esos errores sino que simplemente se redireccionara a la pagina principal, espero me puedan ayudar

```
            //index.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" >



    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/1_ico.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title> | Login </title>
</head>
<body background="img/1_fondo.jpeg">
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->



<form class="formulario">
    
    <h1>Login</h1>
     <div class="contenedor">
     
         <div class="input-contenedor">

         <i class="fas fa-envelope icon"></i>

         <input type="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" maxlength="50" required>
         
         </div>
         
         <div class="input-contenedor">
        <i class="fas fa-key icon"></i>
         <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" maxlength="30" required>
         
         </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button">
         <p>Al registrarte, aceptas nuestras Condiciones de uso y Política de privacidad.</p>
         <p>¿No tienes una cuenta? <a class="link" href="registros.php">Registrate </a></p>
     </div>
    </form>
            

 <!------------------------<script src="js/form.js"></script>--------------------------------------------------------------->

  


    
</body>
</html>

            //registros.php
<?php

$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd");

if (!$enlace) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}



//echo "Éxito: Se realizó una conexión apropiada a MySQL! La base de datos mi_bd." . PHP_EOL;
//echo "Información del host: " . mysqli_get_host_info($enlace) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($enlace);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> | Registro</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" >

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/1_ico.png" type="image/x-icon">
    

</head>  
<body background="img/1_fondo.jpeg">



 <form class="formulario" action="conexion.php" method="post">
    
    <h1>Registrate</h1>
     <div class="contenedor">
     
     <div class="input-contenedor">
         <i class="fas fa-user icon"></i>
         <input type="text" id="myCheck_user_nam" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" name="user_nam" maxlength="20" required>
         
         </div>
         
         <div class="input-contenedor">
         <i class="fas fa-envelope icon"></i>
         <input type="email" id="myCheck_correo_electroni" placeholder="Correo Electronico" name="correo_electroni" maxlength="40" required>
         
         </div>
         
         <div class="input-contenedor">
        <i class="fas fa-key icon"></i>
         <input type="password" id="myCheck_contrase" placeholder="Contraseña" name="contrase" maxlength="15" required>
         
         </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Registrate" class="button" >
         <p>Al registrarte, aceptas nuestras Condiciones de uso y Política de privacidad.</p>
         <p>¿Ya tienes una cuenta?<a class="link" href="index.php">Iniciar Sesion</a></p>


     </div>
    </form>

   



</body>
</html>

     //conexion.php

<?php 

    $conectar =mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','bd') or die ('Error al conectar con el servidor');
    $user_name= $_POST["user_nam"];
    $correo_electronico = $_POST["correo_electroni"];
    $contrasena = $_POST["contrase"];
    echo $contrasena;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO formulario VALUES ('$correo_electronico','$user_name','$contrasena')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);
    mysqli_close($conectar);

    if(empty($_POST['user_nam']) && empty($_POST['correo_electroni']) && empty($_POST['contrase'])){

    echo("Redireccionando...");
    }else{

    echo '<font color="white"><h2> Registro completado con éxito</h2>
    <h3>Gracias por registrarse vuelta pronto </3></font> ';

    echo("<script> alert('Los datos se han registrado satisfactoriamente') </script>");
    }
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Redireccionando</title>
</head>
<body background="img/1_fond.jpeg">




    <script src="js/cambiarLogin.js"></script>


</body>
 

</html>  

       //script javascript


<script>
window.location.assign("index.php");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En un principio te diría que lo correcto es que manejes el registro mediante ajax y que dejes fuera del acceso normal el archivo que se conecta a la db.

Por otro lado si estas empezando a aprender php o algo por el estilo y quieres seguir de esa forma para practicar no veo porque no puedas ponerlo dentro del condicional así sabes que solo accesará si llena los valores.

```
         //conexion.php

<?php 



    if(empty($_POST['user_nam']) && empty($_POST['correo_electroni']) && empty($_POST['contrase'])){

    //lugar que quieras redirigirlo
    header("Location:example.php");

    }else{
    $conectar =mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','bd') or die ('Error al conectar con el servidor');
    $user_name= $_POST["user_nam"];
    $correo_electronico = $_POST["correo_electroni"];
    $contrasena = $_POST["contrase"];
    echo $contrasena;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO formulario VALUES ('$correo_electronico','$user_name','$contrasena')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);
    mysqli_close($conectar);
    echo '<font color="white"><h2> Registro completado con éxito</h2>
    <h3>Gracias por registrarse vuelta pronto </3></font> ';

    echo("<script> alert('Los datos se han registrado satisfactoriamente') </script>");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Gracias!! tú respuesta me soluciono el problema nunca pense en hacer el if y el else de esa manera muchas gracias

Si por el momento estoy comezando a aprender desde 0 sobre los login